# Monotorrent sample client don't download some torrents

Tags: c#, bittorrent, monotorrent

I want to write an application in C# that will use monotorrent open source lib to download torrents.
As a start I'm trying to download some torrents using the sample client in the [lib](https://github.com/mono/monotorrent) like this [torrent](http://torrage.com/torrent/D42D46D2E1DD9AE872EB77AE94768F514B253D25.torrent) but the download does not start, this torrent downloads OK to me on uTorrent.
I suspect that this has something to do with the udp trackers because I could download some torrents who had only http trackers, but I'm not sure.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this problem. I've searched the branches on GitHub that forked from monotorrent and found this [submit](https://github.com/ErtyHackward/monotorrent/commit/7c02f300c9a0a53186e7a260b3d96224a951121e), I've integrated it to monotorrent source code and compiled and it now works.

I hope this will help anyone else encountering this problem in the future.